# How to handle the mac integrated About MenuBar item in Qt QML?

Tags: macos, qt, qml, menubar

I created a QML app under Mac, but I don't know what happens when I click the about menu.

In http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html, we find things about **QMenuBar on OS X**. But what's the corresponding QML method?

Currently, my code is:

```
Menu {
    title: qsTr("&File")
    MenuItem {
        text: qsTr("&Open")
        onTriggered: messageDialog.show(qsTr("Open action triggered"))
    }
    MenuItem {
        text: "about.*"
        onTriggered: console.debug("FDF")
    }
    MenuItem {
        text: qsTr("E&xit")
        onTriggered: Qt.quit()
    }
}
```

When I execute, this menu only shows *Open*, and *About* and *Exit* are correctly integrated into the mac menu. The exit is fine, but when I click *about*, it just quits normally.

So how do we handle that?

Comment: That's quite strange. It perfectly works for me. Which version of OSX/Qt?

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Thank you for your confirmation. I created a new project using my code above, and it did work fine. And later I found the catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. My code is like this,

```
menuBar: MenuBar {

    Menu {
        title: qsTr("&File")
        MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("&Open")
            onTriggered: messageDialog.show(qsTr("Open action triggered"))
        }

        MenuItem {
            text: "about.*"
            onTriggered: console.debug("FDF")
        }

        MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("E&xit")
            onTriggered: Qt.quit()
        }
    }

    Menu {
        title: qsTr("&Help")
        MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("&Help")
            onTriggered: messageDialog.show(qsTr("Open action triggered"))
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("&About")
            onTriggered: Qt.quit()
        }
    }
}
```

There are two `about` menu items, and the latter overrides the previous one.

Comment: I see. Good to hear that you found your issue. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
menuBar: MenuBar {

    Menu {
        title: qsTr("&File") // Name

        MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("&Open") // Name
            onTriggered: messageDialog.show(qsTr("Open action triggered")) // Action on Triggered
        }

        MenuItem {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```